# Javascript regex extract image name from css

Tags: javascript, regex

with javascript regex I´m trying to get the image name and extension as capture group of css properties.

**Requirements**

- starting with url
- followed by brackets
- inside brackets optional quotes
- location can have path information
- ending with jpeg or jpg or gif or png

**Example:**

```
behavior: url(#default#VML);                   -> ignored wrong ending
background-image: url(dog.ttf);                -> ignored wrong ending
background-image: url('cat.png');              -> cat.png
background-image: url(bird.gif);               -> bird.gif
background-image: url('../monkey.png');        -> monkey.png
background-image: url('../../rab$bit.png');    -> rab$bit.png
background-image: url('../animal/cow.jpg');    -> cow.jpg
```

**This is what I have so far:**

```
url(?:\(\"|\(\'|\(\/?.*\/|\()(\.+)?(\/.*\/)?(\w*)+(.png|.jpg|.gif|.jpeg)
```

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/3mMdTI/6

Unfortunately due to the '\w' group this breaks when a filename has digits or characters like $. Can one suggest a better solution?

Comment: Can you post a sample url to check against?

Comment: instead of the `/w` you can just use `[^\'\"]` (negated set of single- and doublequotes to match all but the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are asking for image name with format only not path and other thing.

```js
var string = `behavior: url(#default#VML);                   
background-image: url(dog.ttf);                
background-image: url('cat.png');              
background-image: url(bird.gif);               
background-image: url('../monkey.png');        
background-image: url('../../rab$bit.png');    
background-image: url('../animal/cow.jpg');`

var result = string.match(/[\w\.\$]+(?=png|jpg|gif)\w+/g)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: ah unfortunately rab$it.png fails ;(

Comment: @tBook try now it include `rab$it.png` fully.

Comment: Nice thanks a lot Abhishek Gurjar, this does it! Just for learning if it´s not to hard. Do you see a way to capture the file path before the filename as group as well, f.e. `$0 ->../animal/ $1 -> cow.jpg` ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you like this one:

```
var rx = /([^\/('"\\]+)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)/i
```

In the square brackets I put all chars that are not supposed to be in the name of the image  `/, \, ', ", (` You may add or remove according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(.*\/)?(.*?.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$)
```

2nd group will be image name

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var string = `behavior: url(#default#VML);
background-image: url(home_bbbbbb_14.ttf);
background-image: url('home.ttf');
background-image: url('home.png');
background-image: url(images/home_bbbbbb_14.png);
background-image: url('images/home_bbbbbb_14.jpeg');
background-image: url("images/home_bbbbbb_14.png");
background-image: url(home_bbbbbb_14.png);
background-image: url('home_bbbbbb$_14.png');
background-image: url("home_bbbbbb_14.png");
background-image: url("../img/home_bbbbbb_14.png");
background-image: url("./img/home_bbbbbb_14.png");
background-image: url("../../img/home_bbbbbb_14.jpg");
url("images/animated-overlay.gif");
url("images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png");
url('select2.png');
url(select2x2.png);
url('../images/back_enabled.png');
url('../pic/back_enabled.png');`

var result = string.match(/(?!url)([^\/('"\\]+)\.(?=png|jpg|gif|jpeg)('|"|)\w+/g)

console.log(result)
```